# Getting name of the token with one alternative

Tags: antlr4

Right now, ANTLR does not return Lexer token name if the token contains only one alternative, e.g. for token `SUZY : 'Suzy';` `'Suzy'` will be encoded in the parse tree.

Now, I use token names to encode some useful information, e.g. `SUZY_GENDER_FEMALE : 'Suzy';`.

I have found two solutions so far to get the token name even if the token contains only one alternative:

1. Repeat the same alternative in the token: `SUZY_GENDER_FEMALE : 'Suzy' | 'Suzy';`
2. Use `fragment` keyword:

```
SUZY_GENDER_FEMALE : SUZY_FRAGMENT;
fragment SUZY_FRAGMENT : 'Suzy';
```

Both of these solutions work but are not ideal. I was looking into ANTLR implementation to change the behavior of tokens with one alternative in a way that their names will be returned but the code is quite complex and it will take some time eventhough the change might be quite easy.

Would someone know where to look in the code? (maybe it is as easy as adding one line at the proper place) Or perhaps I am misusing the token names and I should use a different ANTLR mechanism to get the information I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lexer has a static `VOCABULARY`. Try this on it:

```
Token token = ...
String tokenName = YourLexer.VOCABULARY.getSymbolicName(token.getType());
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it. I was actually using deprecated method to get the token name: `parser.getTokenNames()[token.getType()];` - that was the problem.